# Can not push to Github getting "Connection reset by peer" error

Tags: heroku, github, openssh

I have a simple rails test app and have been pushing commits to github w/o a problem. I went to setup w/ heroku, (created the app, loaded up ssh keys) and when I went back to push changes to github before pushing to heroku I got this error:

```
$ git push
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

When I run:

```
ssh -vT git@github.com
```

I get:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "myemail@example.com"OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [207.97.227.239] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

I have replaced my email and username here. I have been searching around on this one for a while and have yet to find somebody who has revolved it. I have reset my keys w/ github to no avail. Any ideas on this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a Heroku issue, Github are having issues.

https://status.github.com/

Comment: Wow, this seems simple enough. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I have been having this issues since yesterday, and github status is fine. it seems to be somehting with the id_rsa